# Theory behind changing what django view display based on python script

Tags: python, django

Hey I want to change image on my webiste based on python script that running in the background and I have no idea how to do it. Script is running continually turning on and off devices and if device is on I want to change what my view display. How do I do it? I have one idea but I dont know if it is good, creating a table in database with boolean values and in my scripts updating a value True/False and in django reading data from database and passing it to view and then using it. Is it good idea? Or there is better option?

Here i come up with simple implemenation but I cant return any object from state model.
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import S280119514568Ff,S280000020E3120,S280119514568Ff,S2801195146F4Ff,S280119514D1Eff,S28011951743Bff,S285A1993D983Ff,S285A1993Ed66Ff,S285A1993F99Fff, Sensors, max31856, state
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    context = {
        's1':S280119514D1Eff.objects.last(),

        }
    return render(request, 'ftemp/home.html', context)

def smoke(request):
    return render(request, 'ftemp/smoke.html')

def refresh_data(request):
    context = {
        'termometry': Sensors.objects.all(),
        's1':[
            S280000020E3120.objects.last(),
            S280119514568Ff.objects.last(),
            S2801195146F4Ff.objects.last(),
            S28011951743Bff.objects.last(),
            S285A1993D983Ff.objects.last(),
            S285A1993Ed66Ff.objects.last(),
            S285A1993F99Fff.objects.last(),
            S280119514D1Eff.objects.last(),
            max31856.objects.last(),
            ],
        'data': S280000020E3120.objects.last().date,
        'pumps': state.objects.all(),
        }
    return render(request, 'ftemp/refresh_data.html', context)
```

my template refresh_data.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  {% for s in s1 %}
  <div class="S{{s.sensor.id}}">
        <table>
          <!-- <td>{{s.sensor.id}}</td> -->
          <!--    <td>{{s.sensor.description}}</td> -->
          <!-- <td>{{s.sensor.sensor_name}}</td> -->
          <td>{{s.temprature}}</td>
          <!-- <td>{{s.date}}</td> -->
        </table>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <div class="data">Ostatni odczytany pomiar: {{data}} </div>
  <div class='pumps'>
          Stan pomp
          <table>
                  {{pumps}}
          </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class state(models.Model):
    pumpCWU = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    pumpCO = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    d4o = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    d4c = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table='state'
```

Output from python3 manage.py shell

```
from ftemp.models import state
>>> state.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<state: state object (1)>]>
>>> state.objects.last().pumpCWU
False
```

And I can see all 'termometry' 'data' but with 'pumps' state.object.all() i expect that i see queryset of this table but all I see is blank page where `{{pumps}}` should be. Any ideas why?

Comment: That'd be the most straightforward way to do this, yes.

Comment: Pumps is just rendering a queryset, not objects, you have to extract the objects.

Comment: @alvo problem was I forgot I push my project to raspbery and was hosting it via apache after restarting service site updates, It took me way too long to figure that out. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't post code, you're not gonna get a comprehensive answer, however you can easily change what view you display to people inside of a view, for example:

```
def home(request):
    if some.condition:
       return redirect('some-other-view')
    elif some.other.condition:
       return redirect('some-other-view')

    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html')
```

Comment: I can't post code if I dont have one thats why I named the question 'theory' because I want to know a way to do it. And maybe some throw some concept/idea at me and point to the right track. I dont really want someone write code for me because I want to learn it but I didnt have idea how to do it and how to connect my python script and django together. I'm apologize for this little disinformation.